# How to update date in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on wpf project in which I have to show update customer's date. So, I have webservice method to update whole customer's info but date is not changing. I think there might be a problem in string format but I have tried everything. Please Help!
Thanks!

here is xaml code for datepicker

```
<Label Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DatePicker 
        x:Name="newtally" 
        Text="{Binding CustomerLastTally}"  
        Margin="0 0 0 0" 
        SelectedDateChanged="newtallydate"
        />
</Label>
```

& here is webservice method in C#

```
private void newtallydate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    webHandler.POS_Update_CustomerAsync(
        int.Parse(selected.Customerid), 
        selected.CustomerName, 
        Decimal.Parse(selected.Customerbalance), 
        selected.CustomerLocation, 
        selected.CustomerLastTally, 
        (selected.Customerphone), 
        (selected.Customeraddress));
}
```

Comment: You haven't used the date selected in any fashion or the value bound to text(CustomerLastTally), I think you need to provide more code and tell us what you expected to happen. Presumably you intended to bind CustomerLastTally to selected.CustomerLastTally? What's the parent datacontext?

Comment: Try binding to the DatePicker's `SelectedDate` property instead of `Text`: `SelectedDate="{Binding CustomerLastTally}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two way binding.

Below is my viewmodel class

```
public class UpdateDateViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _customerTally;

    public UpdateDateViewModel()
    {
        CustomerLastTally = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public DateTime CustomerLastTally
    {
        get { return _customerTally; }
        set
        {
            if (_customerTally != value)
            {
                _customerTally = value;
                updateWebservice();
                OnPropertyChanged("CustomerLastTally");
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateWebservice()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the view code..

```
<Grid>
    <DatePicker 
    x:Name="newtally" 
    Text="{Binding CustomerLastTally,Mode=TwoWay}"  
    Margin="0 0 0 0" 
    />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SelectedDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property of `DatePicker` ..

```
 <DatePicker x:Name="newtally" SelectedDate="{Binding CustomerLastTally}"  
             Margin="0 0 0 0"  SelectedDateChanged="newtallydate" />
```